# Appium - App closes before test gets completed

Tags: java, android, testng, appium

I have a windows 7 and I am testing an Android Native app using Appium. The framework used is TestNG.  I use Java. Appium waits for 60 seconds before closing the app. The search results in the app take some time (esp. when Appium is used) Now there are times when I have inserted waits so that the app doesn't close, but to to no avail. In @After i have even removed driver.close().This is leading to tests not getting completed

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the appium session by adding a capability
"newCommandTimeout".

For Ex: If you want to wait for 5 mins.

> capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 60 * 5);

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to make sure that the app doesn't just close when waiting on a test. First off, you can set an idle timeout, command timeout, and/or max duration for your tests. Sauce Labs has [documentation](https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#timeouts) on those timeouts. I believe you can set those in DesiredCapabilities as well:

```
protected DesiredCapabilities capabilities;

public void setIdleTimeout(String idleTimeout) {
    if (idleTimeout != null && !idleTimeout.isEmpty()) {
        this.capabilities.setCapability("idle-timeout", idleTimeout);
    }
}

public void setCommandTimeout(String commandTimeout) {
    if (commandTimeout != null && !commandTimeout.isEmpty()) {
        this.capabilities.setCapability("command-timeout", commandTimeout);
    }
}

public void setMaxDuration(String maxDuration) {
    if (maxDuration != null && !maxDuration.isEmpty()) {
        this.capabilities.setCapability("max-duration", maxDuration);
    }
}
```

Secondly, you may need to introduce a fluentWait if your test is waiting to assert the search results. You can set a custom timeout and polling interval with fluentWait. Selenium has [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) on this.

Answer (score 0):

One options is to `setCapability`.

```
capabilities.setCapability(COMMAND_TIMEOUT_KEY, COMMAND_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
```

Another option is to wait for some change on the target page with a timeout.

```
public boolean waitForElement(String element,  int timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, timeout / 1000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: timeout value is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

**newCommandTimeout** : How long (in seconds) Appium will wait for a new command from the client before assuming the client quit and ending the session

for eg :

```
 capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 1000); // wait for 1000 milliseconds to run new command
```